# Executing JSP within java

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I am trying to execute a JSP on my local machine by making a URL connection but i can't seem to get it to execute, i thought it could be the java not finding the JSP but i can't seem to find out why this could be as the URL to the JSP looks fine,  anybody have an idea why it isn't executing? My code fragment and webapp structure is below.

Thanks.

```
       URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.jsp");
       URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
       connection.setDoOutput(true);
       OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
       out.write("id=" + id);
       out.close();

       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
       String output;
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       boolean started = false;

       while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
           if (!output.trim().equals("")) {
                started = true;
           }
            if (started) {
                sb.append(output);
                sb.append("\r\n");
            }
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

My Webapp has a similar structure to the following.

```
 webapp
    /WEB-INF
         /classes
         web.xml
    /folder1
       /folder2
          /folder3
             test.jsp
```

Comment: When you paste the URL directly into a browser does it work?

Comment: What kind of message do you get back? Do you get a 404 or any kind of HTTP error code?

Comment: @Thihara the JSP runs fine in the web browser.

Comment: @Usman Mutawakil  Nope the UrlConnection just goes on like nothing has happened no errors or no print messages from the JSP to confirm it is working. At least if it threw an error i would no where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be due to a redirect from `**http**://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.jsp` to `**https**://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.jsp` , wasn't the easiest redirect to spot when i opened the JSP in my browser what was very annoying is the url.openConnection() seemed to carry on like nothings happened.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might intend to do the following (without the outputting part):

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.jsp?id=" + id);
```

Use a StringBuilder for `output` - it is much more efficient.

---

Should text.jsp do both: ask in a form for `id`, and handle the form, then do *not* use:

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    ... handle given id
    return;
}
... show form
```

but use the GET/POST agnostic/irrelevant code:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
if (id != null) {
    ... handle given id
    return;
}
... show form
```

So that the HTTP GET you are doing works.

Comment: Didn't make a difference.

Comment: @JCS What happens if you leave out the check on empty line? Maybe that is it. Was it to skip HTTP header lines?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing your application name. If you are running your app inside tomcat then default port is 8080.

```
http://127.0.0.1:<port>/<web-app-name>/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.jsp
```

Comment: my webapp can be accessed without the app name from http://127.0.0.1, because of the context path i have set for the webapp in the ROOT.xml, but i did still try your way unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I give a troubleshooting approach below, given I don't know much about what failure message you are receiving.

1. I would try accessing another web page other than the URL you
   provided; just to prove your URLConnection approach is correct and
   that it is an issue with access to the JSP file.
2. Look into the actual message/page being returned by your request.
       Is it a 404 page? If so then your URL is off.
3. And ensure you can access that URL directly in your browser.